# Contextual filter by node reference ID

Tags: views, 8

Since good 10 years I work with Views in Drupal. Seems I am just to stupid to get it :)
I tried really every combination but I am not able to put out a working block view with articles, which are referenced to the current node.

We have two node types:

```
- Articles
  -  field (relationship to product node)
- Products
```

Some articles have a relationship (node reference field) to products. When on the node page the view blog should output every 'article', that has a relationship to the current node (product).

I tried to add a contextual filter (node id from url) and a relationship (field_node_reference).
The contextual filter uses then this relationship. However, I know this is not enough.

Results are 0
Which steps are involved? What have I forgotten?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try first with a hardcoded node id. Once that is working, check if the node id in URL is working.